# Must an unused volatile parameter be honoured?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

If I call a function which has a volatile parameter, and that parameter is not used, must the compiler nonetheless produce the parameter?

```
void consume( volatile int ) { }

...

consume( some_expr );
```

GCC does honour this, but I'm uncertain if the wording of volatile in the standards requires this. In my opinion GCC is doing the right thing -- this is logically an assignment to a volatile variable and thus should not be omitted (according to 1.9-8 of the c++ standard)

*NOTE:* The purpose of this is to prevent the optimizer from removing the evaluation of code. That is, it forces `some_expr` to be evaluated. It allows the expression to be optimized, but ensures it is actually performed.

*I've add C and C++ as tags as the answer to both interests me should there be any differences. I don't think there would be however.*

**ANSWER**: I've picked the first one as I believe it is the correct practical realization of the standard. However, Steve's philosophical viewpoint is very interesting and may in fact mean the standard is ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unnamed argument of `consume` cannot be read, since it's unnamed. However, it is initialized, and that initialization (with `some_expr`) is a visible side-effect. Therefore the compiler may not optimize the initialization out.

Whether this requires the actual evalution of `some_expr` is another matter. In general that is not a visible side-effect, but it could be if `some_expr` contains `volatile` sub-expressions.

[edit]
Please note that the "unnamed" part can occur in two places. The caller in general has no way to know whether a parameter is named (let alone used) E.g.

```
void consume( volatile int x);
consume( some_expr );
// other .cpp
void consume( volatile int ) { } // Same function.
```

Comment: Yes, I understand about `some_expr`, that is my intent. The compiler can still optimize that however it wants but the _real value_ of that calculation (as dictated by the abstract machine) must somehow be obtained to assign to the volatile.

Comment: True, but that could be available via Common Subexpression Elimination, for instance. My point is that if the compiler magically knows `some_expr==5`, initializing the unnamed argument with 5 is still observable.

Comment: Yes, I think we are agreeing on that. I admit, it sounds really strange as the use is not immediately apparent, but it does help me a lot in performance testing.

Comment: As to your edit, in the types of things I am testing I am intending that the function call itself is inlined and disappears, and only the assignment remains. That is, named or unnamed the optimizer will certainly know the value is not used.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: I use a "volatile sink" for that: `template<typename T> void consume(T& const t) { T volatile sink = t; }`.

Comment: Actually, my function is a template as well. If I understand the answer correctly however, the shorter version I show should be sufficient. That is, the observable behavior is the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to argue the opposite, but I think an implementation may omit accesses to automatic `volatile` objects, provided that they otherwise make no difference to the program and provided also that it either forbids the programmer from observing the stack (via unmapped or read-only pages, debuggers and so on), or at least warns that doing so won't always have the effect you expect. An unnamed parameter fits that description.

The reason is that the "as-if" rule talks about visible side-effects, and says that volatile accesses are visible side-effects. But if the program itself doesn't depend in any way on them, then the standard *doesn't* say that the object must actually be located "on the stack". The standard allows it to be in a special memory location provided by the hardware, that cannot be read by any means, only written to, and writing to it has no physical effect on the hardware. Since that's permitted, it seems absurd to say it's "required by the standard" that this no-effect write actually goes ahead. How would anyone know? The standard doesn't mandate that there must be instructions in the binary to perform the write, it mandates that the magic, unreadable secret object must assume a particular value. If I claim it has that value, you can't prove I'm wrong :-)

It's not possible to write a conforming program that relies on such a volatile access actually occurring, or to detect whether or not `some_expr` was evaluated. Really it's between you and your debugger whether it was computed or not. I've seen debuggers go wrong for less.

So, I think an implementation is *allowed* to break its own debugger, just as it's *allowed* not to provide a working debugger at all. I don't immediately see why it would want to. In practice I'd expect that marking the parameter volatile has about the same effect as moving the definition of the function somewhere the optimizer can't find it -- it will act to ensure that the value could be used.

Comment: The assignment, however it is done, is an observable side-effect to the processor -- it actually has to do something. It need not be real variable, and could be a register, or some special location, but my understanding/hope is that the assignment really has to be done -- even if nothing could read it. So the question could be rephrased as "does volatile trump the as-if rule?"

Comment: Looking at the standard, a volatile is _by definition_ an observable behavior (last paragraph in 1.9-8). So even if the compiler can determine the value cannot be used, it must still assign the value somewhere.

Comment: The question _how_ to observe something is related to the question _whether_ it can be observed, but it's certainly not the same question. Perhaps this thread should be continued on Philosophy.SE ;)

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: I agree that by definition a volatile write is "observable behavior", but that doesn't mean it can in fact be observed :-). The implementation is at liberty to write however it likes - one word at a time in the case of a DWORD variable, or with a read-mask-write. If the implementation knows that it makes no difference to the processor how the write is done (or whether it's done at all), then I don't see how the standard can possibly legislate where it can't enforce. But that's a big if - in fact there's quite possibly a stack slot assigned even for an unused parameter.

Comment: I suppose really I'm saying that there's another, bigger "as-if" rule outside the standard, which says that if the implementation cannot be distinguished from one that conforms to the standard by any possible real measurement, then it conforms. As MSalters says, that's a philosophical question as much as anything. And in a case like this, implementations often do provide means to make those measurements (mainly debuggers), they just don't have to.

Comment: SO, as long as the optimizer has not philosopher oracle in it which can answer these questions I should be safe. :)